# Management of Rundeck via Ansible

Tags: rundeck

*scenario*

There is a Rundeck server, which is Ansible managed.

Question:
What is the easiest way to add projects in Rundeck via Ansible, so we don't have to touch the web-GUI of Rundeck. I've heard that the API isn't really a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck API is a good option I think, you can do it anything with it:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/

And a good reference:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k#intro

Another option, if you want, is use RD CLI for that:

https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/